# Java Number Guessing Program Issue

Tags: java

I have a beginning Java Program I have been working on that creates a number guessing program where the computer guesses a number that the user is thinking of within a certain range. 
I so far have the program below, but need help getting rid of a few kinks/ adding features.
-First, I need to set it up so that the user will be prompted and give a range. It should run and produce something like this:
Welcome to this first-ever mind-guessing program!

Please pick a range (higher than 1 and no larger than 50): 32

You will choose a number between 1 and 32... and I will try to guess it.

With each of my guess, you will tell me whether I am too high (h or H), 
too low (l or L), match (m or M), or you want to quit (q or Q). My 
objective is to find the number using as few guesses as possible.

-Second, the game is supposed to give up and restart after failing the five, guesses, but for some reason, after it fails the fifth time, it prompts a fifth guess once again instead, then restarts after- I need to prevent this, so that it should look something like this: 
My fourth guess is 17: h
My guess is too high?

My fifth guess is 16: h
*** I am unlucky this round. I give up.

Let's play!

My first guess is 10:
etc..

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class numguessprac1 {

    // Declaring variables
    public static String input;
    public static int    quit;
    public static int    guess;
    public static int    wins;
    public static int    guessNum;
    public static int    losses;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to my first-ever mind-reading     program!\n");
        System.out.println("You will choose a number between 1 and 32... and    I will try to guess it.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("With each of my guess, you will tell me whether     I am too high (h or H),\n" +
        "too low (l or L), match (m or M), or you want to quit (q or Q).    My\n" +
        "objective is to find the number using as few guesses as     possible.");   

        int totalGuessNum = 0;

        while (quit != 1) {
            System.out.println();
            gamePlay( numbersAsWords() );
            totalGuessNum =+ guessNum;
        } // Loop end

        printStats(totalGuessNum);

    } // Main end

    public static int gamePlay( String numbersAsWords ) {

        int countdown;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r  = new Random();
        guess     = r.nextInt(2) + 16;  

        System.out.println("Let's play!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("My " + numbersAsWords() + " guess is " + guess +     ": ");
        String input = s.nextLine();

        for (countdown = 3; countdown >= -1; countdown--) {

            if (countdown == -1 && !input.equals("M") && !input.equals("m"))     {
                System.out.println("*** I am unlucky this round. I give     up.");
                losses++;
                break;
            } else if
            (input.equals("Q") || input.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("*** You quit!");
                quit = 1;
                break;
            } else if
            (input.equals("M") || input.equals("m")) {
                System.out.println("*** Correct!");
                guessNum++;
                wins++;
                break;
            } else if
            (input.equals("H") || input.equals("h")) {
                System.out.println("My guess is too high?");
                guessNum++;
                guess = guess - (int) Math.pow(2, countdown);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("My " + numbersAsWords() + " guess is " +     guess + ": ");
            } else if
            (input.equals("L") || input.equals("l")) {
                System.out.println("My guess is too low?");
                guessNum++;
                guess = guess + (int) Math.pow(2, countdown);
                System.out.print("\nMy " + numbersAsWords() + " guess is " +        guess + ": ");
            } else if (!input.equals("M")) {
                System.out.println("Sorry I do not understand your    response.\n");
                System.out.print("My " + numbersAsWords() + " guess is " +    guess + ": ");
                countdown++;
            }

            input = s.nextLine();

        } // End for loop

        return quit;

    } // End of playGame

    public static void printStats(int totalGuessNum) {

        double ratio;
        int    totalGames = wins + losses;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("My overall results:");
        System.out.println("Total games\t\t = " + totalGames);
        System.out.println("Succeeded games\t\t = " + wins);

        if (wins != 0) {
            ratio = (double) totalGuessNum / (double) wins;
            System.out.printf("Guesses/succ. game:\t = %1.1f\n", ratio);
        }
        else if (wins == 0) {
            ratio = 0;
            System.out.println("Guesses/succ. game:\t = " + ratio);
        }

        System.out.println("Gave-up games\t\t = " + losses);

    } // End of smartGuessMeth

    public static String numbersAsWords() {

        String ordinalWord = "first";
        switch (guessNum) {
            case 1: ordinalWord = "second";   break;
            case 2: ordinalWord = "third";    break;
            case 3: ordinalWord = "fourth";   break;
            case 4: ordinalWord = "fifth";    break;

        }
        return ordinalWord;

    } // 

} // End of class
```

Comment: Are you trying brute force technique? :|

Answer (score 0):

You haven't reset the counter  `guessNum`

```
if (countdown == -1 && !input.equals("M") && !input.equals("m"))     {
                System.out.println("*** I am unlucky this round. I give     up.");
                losses++;
                guessNum = 0;
                break;
```

Will do the trick.